# tool tip without mouse hover

Tags: html, css

I created an inline help tip using http://tutorialzine.com/2014/07/css-inline-help-tips/ based on html css.Below given code works on **mouse hover on help icon it shows some text** but what i need is **automatically show the mouse hover text that is "hello pls help" with out mouse hover** i need the mouse hover information to show automatically once the page loads.Thanks in advance

```css
.help-tip{
  position: absolute;
  top: 18px;
  right: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #BCDBEA;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 26px;
  cursor: default;
}

.help-tip:before{
  content:'?';
  font-weight: bold;
  color:#fff;
}

.help-tip:hover p{
  display:block;
  transform-origin: 100% 0%;

  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 0.3s ease-in-out;
  animation: fadeIn 0.3s ease-in-out;

}

.help-tip p{ /* The tooltip */
  display: none;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #1E2021;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  right: -4px;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 1.4;
}

.help-tip p:before{ /* The pointer of the tooltip */
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width:0;
  height: 0;
  border:6px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color:#1E2021;
  right:10px;
  top:-12px;
}

.help-tip p:after{ /* Prevents the tooltip from being hidden */
  width:100%;
  height:40px;
  content:'';
  position: absolute;
  top:-40px;
  left:0;
}

/* CSS animation */

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% { 
    opacity:0; 
    transform: scale(0.6);
  }

  100% {
    opacity:100%;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:100%; }
}
```

```html
<div class="help-tip">
  <p id="helpinforchart">hello pls help</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

simply add display:block in place of display:none

```
.help-tip p
{
display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the display:none from the css as below

```css
.help-tip{
 position: absolute;
 top: 18px;
 right: 18px;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: #BCDBEA;
 border-radius: 50%;
 width: 24px;
 height: 24px;
 font-size: 14px;
 line-height: 26px;
 cursor: default;
}

.help-tip:before{
 content:'?';
 font-weight: bold;
 color:#fff;
}

.help-tip:hover p{
 display:block;
 transform-origin: 100% 0%;

 -webkit-animation: fadeIn 0.3s ease-in-out;
 animation: fadeIn 0.3s ease-in-out;

}

.help-tip p{ /* The tooltip */
 
 text-align: left;
 background-color: #1E2021;
 padding: 20px;
 width: 200px;
 position: absolute;
 border-radius: 3px;
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
 right: -4px;
 color: #FFF;
 font-size: 13px;
 line-height: 1.4;
}

.help-tip p:before{ /* The pointer of the tooltip */
 position: absolute;
 content: '';
 width:0;
 height: 0;
 border:6px solid transparent;
 border-bottom-color:#1E2021;
 right:10px;
 top:-12px;
}

.help-tip p:after{ /* Prevents the tooltip from being hidden */
 width:100%;
 height:40px;
 content:'';
 position: absolute;
 top:-40px;
 left:0;
}

/* CSS animation */

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
 0% { 
  opacity:0; 
  transform: scale(0.6);
 }

 100% {
  opacity:100%;
  transform: scale(1);
 }
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
 0% { opacity:0; }
 100% { opacity:100%; }
}
```

```html
<div class="help-tip">
 <p id="helpinforchart">hello pls help</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Removing properties from

```
.help-tip:hover
```

will help you

```css
.help-tip{
 position: absolute;
 top: 18px;
 right: 18px;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: #BCDBEA;
 border-radius: 50%;
 width: 24px;
 height: 24px;
 font-size: 14px;
 line-height: 26px;
 cursor: default;
}

.help-tip:before{
 content:'?';
 font-weight: bold;
 color:#fff;
}

.help-tip p{ /* The tooltip */
 text-align: left;
 background-color: #1E2021;
 padding: 20px;
 width: 200px;
 position: absolute;
 border-radius: 3px;
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
 right: -4px;
 color: #FFF;
 font-size: 13px;
 line-height: 1.4;
 transform-origin: 100% 0%;
 -webkit-animation: fadeIn 0.3s ease-in-out;
 animation: fadeIn 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.help-tip p:before{ /* The pointer of the tooltip */
 position: absolute;
 content: '';
 width:0;
 height: 0;
 border:6px solid transparent;
 border-bottom-color:#1E2021;
 right:10px;
 top:-12px;
}

.help-tip p:after{ /* Prevents the tooltip from being hidden */
 width:100%;
 height:40px;
 content:'';
 position: absolute;
 top:-40px;
 left:0;
}

/* CSS animation */

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
 0% { 
  opacity:0; 
  transform: scale(0.6);
 }

 100% {
  opacity:100%;
  transform: scale(1);
 }
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
 0% { opacity:0; }
 100% { opacity:100%; }
}
```

```html
<div class="help-tip">
 <p id="helpinforchart">hello pls help</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

hume

You can change css like:

```
/* add 'active' class behavior */
.help-tip:hover p,
.help-tip.active p{
    display:block;
    transform-origin: 100% 0%;

    -webkit-animation: fadeIn 0.3s ease-in-out;
    animation: fadeIn 0.3s ease-in-out;

}
```

and change html like:

```
<!-- add 'active' class -->
<div class="help-tip active">
    <p id="helpinforchart">hello pls help</p>
</div>
```

if you want to change the operation behavior to 'hover show', add js like:

```
// native
var tip = document.getElementsByClassName('help-tip')[0];
tip.className = tip.className.replace('active', '');

// jQuery
$('.help-tip').removeClass('active')
```

Comment: or you can just do it like other answer, but you can not get back to hover show

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to add some javascript this jQuery code and .display class keep the hover functionality and display the tooltip on document load:

Css:

```
.display {
  display: block !important;
}
```

jQuery (loaded on the document ´< head>´):

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('#helpinforchart').addClass('display');
  $('.help-tip').mouseleave(function(){
    $('#helpinforchart').removeClass('display');
    $(this).unbind();
  })
});
```

To see it working see this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/r80o6ej8/

Comment: You can also replace the ´:hover´ pseudoclass with some javascript code just like Jelly suggests, and if you don't want to use jQuery you can replace it with base javascript, but you will need to organize your code and to create new functions using JS base functions.